# MongoDB or CouchDB as database for mobile devices?

Tags: mongodb, mobile, couchdb, database, nosql

I wonder if MongoDB and CouchDB could work as database for mobile devices?

If they both can, which one is better to use for online/offline storage?

Comment: By database for mobile device do you mean one connected to over the internet or embedded on the phone?

Comment: Local database embedded on the phone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CouchDB has built in support for offline synchronization.  It would we be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is intended for server only use. It expects to be running in a 64-bit little-endian environment in a cluster of at least two nodes and is not particularly stable without that miniumum configuration.

Comment: MongoDB can run in 32-bit configurations (with limits on maximum data size), and works great in single node configurations. One of my servers has been grinding away with MongoDB for over six months with zero downtime, and it gets several hundred inserts, and several thousand queries a day. While I'll agree it's not intended for embedded use, it's not as heavy as you seem to think it is.

Comment: Right. The max data size with 32 bits is ~2.5 gigs. Also without multiple servers you run the risk of data corruption in the event of a failure (crash, power loss, etc.). http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair "We recommend using replication to keep copies of data for now – and likely forever – as a single server could fail catastrophically regardless."